# Angular - http post - error goes to the success function

Tags: angularjs

I send the post query to the server (Angular v1.5.5) and server returns error 500. But why that error goes to the `success` callback instead of the `error` callback function ? Firebug shows me the `success` message, and no `error` message.

```
$http.post('someURL', someData)
     .success(function (data1) {
          console.log('success');

          return data1;
      })
      .error(function (data2) {
          console.log('error');

          return data2;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax for angular 1.5.5:

```js
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Ref: https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/docs/api/ng/service/$http